# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on bool in

Tags: php, mvc, crud

tengo un CRUD simple en PHP y quiero solucionar este error.

Este el código de modificar.php

```html
<?php
    include "../model/conexion.php";
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    
    $sql = $conexion->query("SELECT * from persona WHERE id_persona=('$id')");
    //Por si hay errores
    if (!$sql) {
        printf("Error: %s\n", $conexion->error);
    }
    
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Modificar Persona - CRUD</title>
    <!--Bootstrap-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid row">
        <form class="col-4" method="POST">
            <h3 class="text-center text-secundary">Modificar personas</h3>
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$_GET["id"]?>">
            <?php
            include "../controller/modificar_persona.php";
            while($datos = $sql->fetch_object()) {             
            ?>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Nombre de la Persona</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre" value="<?=$datos->nombre?>">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Apellido de la Persona</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="apellido" value="<?=$datos->apellido?>">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">DNI de la persona</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="dni" value="<?=$datos->dni?>">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Fecha de Nacimiento</label>
                    <input type="date" class="form-control" name="fecha" value="<?=$datos->fecha_nac?>">
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Correo</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="correo" value="<?=$datos->correo?>">
                </div>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="btnregistrar" value="ok">Modificar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!--Script Bootstrap-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-geWF76RCwLtnZ8qwWowPQNguL3RmwHVBC9FhGdlKrxdiJJigb/j/68SIy3Te4Bkz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--Javascript-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Muy bien y este es el código de modificar_persona.php el cuál trabaja con la base de datos, hace un llamado a los registros que están en el CRUD y los asigna esas variables mostrada, luego a través de una consulta SQL los introduce en mi tabla:

```
`<?php
if(!empty($_POST["btnregistrar"])){
    if(!empty($_POST["nombre"]) AND !empty($_POST["apellido"]) AND !empty($_POST["dni"])
    AND !empty($_POST["fecha"]) AND !empty($_POST["correo"])){
        $id=$_POST["id"];
        $nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
        $apellido=$_POST["apellido"];
        $dni=$_POST["dni"];
        $fecha=$_POST["fecha"];
        $correo=$_POST["correo"];


        $sql=$conexion->query("update persona set nombre='$nombre', apellido='$apellido', dni='$dni', fecha_nac='$fecha', correo='$correo' where id_persona=$id ");

        if($sql==1)
        {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-success"> Modificada Correctamente</div>';
            echo '<script>setTimeout(function(){ window.location.href = "../view/index.php"; }, 2000);</script>';
            
            //header("location:../view/index.php");
        } else{
            echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Error al Modificar Persona</div>';
        }
    }
    else{
        echo '<div class="alert alert-warning">ALGUNOS CAMPOS ESTAN VACIOS</div>';
    }
}
?> `
```

Lo curioso es que mi registro es modificado correctamente, pero siempre me aparece este error en la pantalla, antes de redirigirme a "index.php" el cuál es mi página que muestra todos los registros:

[image: error mostrado]

Comment: Hola. Esto no tiene sentido: `while($datos = $sql->fetch_object()) {` porque tu consulta en ese contexto es del tipo `UPDATE` y ese tipo de consultas no devuelven un conjunto de resultados. Si fuese una consulta del tipo `SELECT` sí podrías hacer `fetch` y leer las filas / columnas que traería la consulta. Si quieres mostrar el nombre, el dni y demás tómalos del `$_POST` que para eso tienes los datos ahí en ese contexto.

Comment: Hola @A. Cedano, estoy utilizando `while($datos = $sql->fetch_object()) {`  en **modificar.php** porque necesito extraer el registro que he seleccionado de la base de datos, cuando yo le doy a editar registro en mi **index.php** ésta abre **modificar.php**, luego cuando le doy a botón de modificar, me sale una alerta de éxito que tiene una animación de 2seg. pero ese mensaje de error persiste a pesar de que funcionar, me recomiendas algún otro método para que en la espera de redirección a **index.php** no me muestre a ese error?